# jQuery,Input buttons work in markup, but not when prepended?

Tags: jquery, dom, prepend

I have to buttons, image input that work fine when in the markup like this,

```
<input type="image" class="play" src="images/play.png" />
<input type="image" class="pause" src="images/pause.png" />
```

But as soon as I try to prepend() it to a generated  they still appear, but
the click function does not work anymore.

```
$('.gallery-nav').prepend('<input type="image" class="play" src="images/play.png" /><input type="image" class="pause" src="images/pause.png" />');
```

Any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: I assume the click function you mean is a javascript based click event?  If so use one of the answers below (.live())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** instead of click.

> live: attach a handler to the event
>   for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now or in the
>   future.

```
$("input.play").live("click", function(){
    // write your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method for that:

```
// for play button
$('.play').live('click', function(){
  // your code
});

// for pause button
$('.pause').live('click', function(){
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mydivClass').prepend('<a href="#" id="btnLINK">OK</a>');

$('#btnLINK').live("click",function() { 
    alert ("EUREKA")
    return false;
});
```